# Pinch Gesture Recognizer resets image on second pinch zoom

Tags: swift

I'm using the UIPinchGestureRecognizer for pinch/zoom and image. If I zoom in with my fingers release them trying to zoom in more the image resets to the org. size for the second zoom in attempt.

How can I get the image to stay "zoomed in" for the second pinch?

here is how I'm doing the UIPinchGestureRecognizer

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.scale, sender.scale)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
            recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
            recognizer.scale = 1
    }
}
```